# How do I code for the landscape orientation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, orientation

I understand that I can change what interface orientations are supported, but if I want the landscape view to be entirely different, or somewhat different than the portrait view, how do I code for it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just load another view controller when the orientation changes. To make things simple, I often use a hidden navigation controller and push and pop the views I want for any particular orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dedicated view controller for each orientation is the easiest approach.

If the only difference is presentation, not controller logic, then you could also try coding a single view controller to swap between two views depending on orientation.

E.g. pseudocode

```
UIView *landscapeView = ...;
UIView *portraitView = ...;

when orientationChanged
{
   if landscape then 
      [portraitView setHidden:YES];
      [landscapeView setHidden:NO];
      self.view = landscapeView;
   else if portrait then
      [landscapeView setHidden:NO];
      [portraitView setHidden:YES];
      self.view = portraitView;


   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```