# How do I code for the landscape orientation in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, screen-orientation

I understand that you can choose what orientations to support, but if I want my landscape orientation to be somewhat different from my portrait, how do I code for it?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420039/how-do-i-code-for-the-landscape-orientation-in-iphone

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

If you would like to open your app directly in landscape mode, you must do this:
1. Open your application Info.plist.
2. Add a new row and set Key as Initial Interface Orientation.
3. Type in the Value field, Landscape (left home button).
4. Save it.

You can change left home button with right home button...
As it your application will start automatically in landscape mode :)